# When is it correct to repeat the Adjective?

Tags: adjectives, coordination

> We are the fans of the American Values and the American model of multiculturalism.
>
> We are the fans of the American Values and model of multiculturalism.
>
> We are the fans of the Values and the model of multiculturalism of America.

Which sentence is right regarding the adjective (*American*)?

Comment: We are fans of American values and the American model of multiculturalism.

Comment: Even when a repeated adjective is not grammatically required, it can be used for emphasis. You could say "we are fans of American values and multiculturalism", or you could say "we are fans of American values and American multiculturalism" to put more emphasis on the fact that it's American.

Comment: Agreeing with @TRomano. Omitting "the American" before model is ambiguous. What model of multiculturalism? The American model of multiculturalism. Also, "values" should not be capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no article before "American values" because you're referring to a wide range of values, but with the model, you're referring to a specific model, hence the definite article.

Comment: TRomano: Thank you very much for this clarification.